# When orientation changes from portrait to landscape accessibility is not focusing the whole view in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiaccessibility

When orientation changes from portrait to landscape, Os changes the sizes of the views which have layout constraints respective to the orientation. When the size of the views change due to orientation, accessibility focus is highlighting the whole view when in Portrait[Accessibility focus of search bar when device is in potrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDxJf.jpg)but in landscape mode the accessibility focus is not highlighting the whole view[Accessibility focus of search bar when device is in landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kurEh.jpg). Its highlighting just part of the view which is equal to the size of the view in portrait mode.

Tried refreshing the page after orientation but seems no use.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Its a big application, its happening with most of the button views in it.I didn't code anything for the button view just gave few layout constraints like distance from view above and from sides thats it.